# Function in onclick of tag <a> passing parameters

Tags: jquery, html

I want to do one function to receive two parameters in jQuery, the parameter need to be configured in a link (tag ), the exemple:

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfuncion(val1, val2);">
```

JS

```
$(function myfuncion(val1, val2) {
    // return 
});
```

is is a good practice? How can I make its work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes surely you can use this approach

In your anchor tag

```
<a href='#' onclick="myfunction(val1,val2)">Add</a>
```

In jquery you can use

```
<script>
function myfunction(id1,id2)
{
alert(id1);
alert(id2);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

in Head script tag add following

```
function myfunction(i,j)
{
  alert(i);
  alert(j);
}
```

then in link

```
<a href="#;" onclick="myfunction(val1,val2)">Test Function</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pure javascript function you are trying to use.So do the following changes:

```
function myfuncion(val1, val2)
{
    //Code
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/narcX/)